# Not owner error in AIX(unix) while getting pgid between processes

Tags: permissions, process, aix

I confront a problem while porting my python program in AIX.

The problem seems on ownership or permission between processes.

Let's assume that there are two processes(`process1`, `process2`).

The processes are in the different process group.

In this situation the `Os Error` happens when the `process1` try to get `pgid` of `procees2` returning `Not Owner` `OsError`.

The problem never happen in `Ubuntu(Linux)`

Please give me any suggentions.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: getpgid is allowed to return EPERM when you try to get the pgid of a process that is not in your process's session. So one way to avoid this is to make sure the processes are created while in the same session.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick : If there is another way by settings OS settings (Permission or something)